# Swiper - 2 Column thumbs slide, active slide not always in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

When I click next on the main "hero" swiper slider multiple times (10). The thumbs in view get out of sync and the active thumb is no longer in view.

I am trying to link two swiper sliders together inside a bootstrap modal. The thumbs slider is a vertical two column slider and linked to the main "hero" slider inside the modal.

Scroll down the page and click "view 23 photos" to open the modal.
https://transmission.mecum.tv/2019/06/18/milk-money/

```
const $id = $(this).attr('id');

modalThumbs = new Swiper('#' + $id + ' .gallery-modal-thumbs .swiper-container', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  observer: true,
  observeParents: true,
  spaceBetween: 20,
  slidesPerColumn: 2,
  slidesPerView: 5,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '#' + $id + ' .modal-thumb-next button',
    prevEl: '#' + $id + ' .modal-thumb-prev button',
  },
});

modalHero = new Swiper('#' + $id + ' .gallery-modal-hero .swiper-container', {
  loop: true,
  observer: true,
  observeParents: true,
  simulateTouch: false,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  speed: 500,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '#' + $id + ' .modal-hero-next button',
    prevEl: '#' + $id + ' .modal-hero-prev button',
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '#' + $id + ' .swiper-pagination',
    type: 'fraction',
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: gallerySliders[$id].modalThumbs,
  },
});
```

The active thumbnail slide should always be in view.

Comment: OT: I wanted to take a look but couldn't find the mentioned link anywhere. [This is a screenshot of the page in FF](https://i.imgur.com/5zsjuPh.jpg), images won't scale properly. Only saw two warnings and no errors in the browser console so it's most likely not due to blocked or missing scripts.

Comment: Looks like I had a flexbox issue there. Should be ok on firefox now.

Comment: Looks really good now in FF!

Answer (score 0):

It seems automatic height calculation along with two-column layout might be problematic. Right now on moving to the next slide the script uses `.translate3d()` on the Y-axis with the heights of one image to scroll the thumbs. If you would manually set the heights via [`Parameters` setting](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#parameters) to the half heights of the image (which would be 52 Pixels rather than 104 Pixels) the currently shown element should not move out of view. Initialization would be similar to this:

```
var thumbsSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container-thumbs', {
  slidesPerView: 10,
  height: 52
});
```

Comment: Where did you get 104px from? The thumbs are 82px. I tried adding a height of 41 as a parameter and now the slides have 0 height?

Comment: @harte11 The 104 comes from 84 Pixel heights plus gap of 20. I tried to create a Fiddle from your page's code but it is too complex to simply move the relevant parts into a Codepen or Fiddle. If you could take care of this, I'll definitely check it and will most likely find a solution for you.

Comment: I'll try but it's buried in a project... I added "WatchSlidesVisibility: true" and it works much better. Clicking next is fine, it's only when you click prev it loses the active one between slides 11-9.

Comment: @harte11 As the docs say "WatchSlidesVisibility should always be enabled". I wonder why the Devs set it to "false" as a  default, then. This will actually be a bug you found and it's worth reporting it on the [Github project issue page](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues) so it will hopefully be fixed soon.